# sigma is unknown, so it must be estimated by using sigma approximately equals (1/4) * (range)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, sample, small-sample

Suppose you want to estimate the average age of all Boeing 737-300 airplanes now in active domestic U.S. service. You want to be 95% confident, and you want your estimate to be within one year of the actual figure. The 737-300 was first placed in service about 24 years ago, but you believe that no active 737-300s in the U.S. domestic fleet are more than 20 years old. How large of a sample should you take?

Solution says that E = 1 year, the z value for 95% is 1.96, and s is unknown, so it must be estimated by using s approximately equals to (1/4) * (range). As the range of ages is 0 to 20 years, s = (1/4)(20) = 5.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why do we use 1/4* range